# Compute nearly equal pattern of a string

Tags: r

Find near duplicate string. Hi, I know there is a match, unique, duplicated function in R, but none of these does wha I'm really need. I've a unique column in my dataset that I need to go trough it to check if the number are nearly the same. For instance, the first element compared with the second has nearly equal pattern, except for the number '9'. The second compared with the third is nearly equal, except for the last number o the sequence, one is ending with 6 while other ending with 5. Lastly, the two last numbers are 100% equal. If I've used `unique()` function, only the last case would be correctly excluded. 
I'm wondering if there is a function that I can flag nearly equal, maybe calculating the percentage of equality, so I can drive my attention to those cases with highly equality rate.

```
  dat <- data.frame(text = c("87775956",
                   "987775956",
                   "987775955",
                   "987481732",
                   "987481732"))
```

Comment: Try reading up on what a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) is. An R implementation is available in the `stringdist` package.

Comment: It may contain the solution, but operationalization is not given, one the function needs tow vectors or sets to compare with and I've only one vector. So I've to compare within the vector, not between.

Comment: `stringdist::stringdistmatrix(dat$text) %>%as.matrix()` would show you all match combinations. 0's on a non diagonal will mean a duplicate string, a 1 will mean there is very near equal match, 2 a nearish match and so on. You could use this to vary your "nearly equal" condition.